# Load a web page inside a html

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to insert a web page into a html file using iframe but showing the this "inserted page" at all browser ?

I need a solution to insert a html with a expansive way.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve? Please show us what you have tried so far. People are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you mean showing the iframe and its "parent" website in fullscreen?

Comment: Yes, DBX12, showing the iframe and its "parent" website in fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear but I will try my best to answer.

if you want the entire page to be taken up with this `<iframe>`, you will have two options:

1. Use jquery's `$().load` function and "load" your other website

`$(function(){
    $("body").load("http://yourWebPageHere");
});`

2. Use plain `<iframe>` tags and use the css `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` to make it extent to the edges.  Note, do not use `width: 100%;` because that will leave a margin around the edges of the page.